# Is function input data type affecting loop speed/efficiency

Tags: excel, vba, function, input

This may be another question that user "don't like" because it's more advice related than problem related.

I have a code that's triggered on save and workbook open.
It selects the right sheet in f(day vs night, date vs actual date).
My condition are the same for monday to wednesday but Thursday as a different schedule, i then want to test

```
instr(ws.name,"Thursday") > 0
```

My questioning was: is it more efficient to input `sheetname as string` or `ws as worksheet` in my test function.

Here the code:

Caller

```
Public Sub SelectionDeQuartAuto()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then
            With ws.Range("B4")
                If .Value = Date Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
    If isDayShift(Now, ws) Then
        Set ws = DayShiftSheet
    Else
        Set ws = NightShiftSheet
    End If
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Vendredi jour").Activate
    Else
        ws.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Function:

```
Public Function isDayShift(DateTime As Date, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Jeudi") > 0 Then
        isDayShift = TimeValue(DateTime) > TimeValue("03:00:00") And TimeValue(DateTime) < TimeValue("15:15:00")
    Else
        isDayShift = TimeValue(DateTime) > TimeValue("03:00:00") And TimeValue(DateTime) < TimeValue("16:15:00")
    End If
End Function
```

Which would become:

```
Public Sub SelectionDeQuartAuto()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim sheetname as string
        ' For etc..
        ' Exit for with right ws
        sheetname = ws.Name
        If isDayShift(Now, sheetname) Then
        ' etc...
End Sub

Public Function isDayShift(DateTime As Date, sheetname As string) As Boolean
    If InStr(sheetname, "Jeudi") > 0 Then
    ' ... rest
End Function
```

If it doesnt matter much and/or my question is unapropriated just say it in comment il leave it that way and delete, thx boys and gurls

Comment: If you declare the return type, i believe it might be unnoticeably more performant because it doesn't have to evaluate the type of the returned variant. But, i would say its best to declare the return type for the sake of clarity/debugging

Comment: Return type would stay the same, i was wondering because ws object are packages of a lot of parameter it would maybe be more efficient or more "standard" to input a string and having the `sheetname = ws.Name` outside of the function?

Comment: "ws object are packages of a lot of parameter" - not sure you're thinking about this the right way. At some point or another you'll have to access `ws.Name`. That said, I don't see how there would be a performance issue with either approach.

Comment: @BigBen well when i look at local variable i can click on + and see a bunch of quotes"parameter" link with the ws variable.. isnt it "bigger" to pass than a "simple" string?

Comment: @PatatesPilées when you pass an object as a parameter, it will pass a reference to that object. So its not really passing around something that is "bigger"

Comment: `ws` is just an object reference. No it's not "bigger."

Comment: Using the `ws` loop variable outside the loop scope looks weird and make the logic dependent on the ordering of the worksheets (`ws` will be pointing to whatever object the last loop iteration was working with) and on whether the loop actually completes at all - I'd consider that a bug, since there's a non-zero possibility that `ws` is `Nothing` after the loop (if all sheets end up being iterated and `Exit For` never runs). The `If ws Is Nothing` condition looks like it will always evaluate to `False`, so that block could be replaced with just `ws.Activate`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon this was made so when we open back the sheet later it always display Vendredi jour (week summary on it),  il look for a way ot simplify it cause it realy do look weird

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not about performance, it's about *responsibilities* and the *Principle of Least Knowledge*.

If all a function needs to know is *the name of a worksheet*, then the best way to write that function is to make it take *the name of a worksheet* as a parameter.

By taking in a `String` rather than a `Worksheet`, you are making the function's purpose clearer, decoupling it from the Excel object model (its logic works with any `String` value which makes it easier to test), and helping to prevent future *scope creep* in its implementation (i.e. if it has access to a `Worksheet` object, then it can do everything such a reference allows it to do).

I would even argue that your function doesn't even care about a *sheet name*, what it really wants to work with is a `weekdayName`, and it being a French-language value probably matters so I'd go with something like `wkDayFrenchName` - the fact that the string value is coming from a `Worksheet` is none of its concern.

```
Public Function IsDayShift(ByVal DateTime As Date, ByVal wkDayFrenchName As string) As Boolean
    If InStr(wkDayFrenchName, "Jeudi") > 0 Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Function
```

Note that the logic could be further streamlined to work out the weekday from just the given date, which would make it both easier to use and more robust:

```
Public Function IsDayShift(ByVal DateTime As Date) As Boolean
    If WeekDay(DateTime, vbSunday) > vbThursday Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Function
```

And now working off a worksheet named `Jeudi` ("Thursday") but containing a `Date` that's actually a `Lundi` ("Monday") will still produce the correct output. Arguably the function could be parameterless and be responsible for working out the current date itself, but it's much more versatile to take the date as a parameter, and the fewer responsibilities a procedure/function has, the better.

Comment: Merci pour le cours gratuits en parallèle, really apreciated! I'll probably need to rework subs and 3 function with that in mind now! VBA power-up!

Comment: @PatatesPilées not sure if you saw, but I just edited this answer again to explain that the function doesn't even need to take a sheet name or weekday name, but taking in a `Date` parameter is a very good idea.

Comment: That's exaclty what i was doing the last 20 minutes haha! ; instead of looking for sheet in f(date vs now, jour vs soir) il now look for sheetname containing weekday+ jour vs soir. Im not sure if functions are actually needed now since its a total 10 line for the original 1 sub + 3 function

Comment: @PatatesPilées no function is ever "actually needed" - the code will happily run with or without additional scopes, parameters, and variables; we split things up by responsibility (each scope *does one thing* and does it well) and *name things* so that the *abstraction level* of the code makes it easier to read, follow, and maintain: 10 lines is pretty much the upper limit for the length of most procedure scopes!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mind about efficiency - you will not be able to measure any difference.

Always use what fits best to your need. Pass a Worksheet if you deal with a worksheet, pass a string if you deal with a string.

If you are sure that you will always have to check a string, pass the sheet name as string. If you maybe change your mind and check if the sheet matches because of another criteria (maybe a cell or a named range), it's maybe better to pass a Worksheet. Just in both cases, use clear names (but you do already).